# Download Counter

Tags: visualforce, outputlink

I have a page with a list PDFs which can be downloaded. Can I count how often a pdf was downloaded?

I tried to solve this problem like

**PAGE:**

```
<apex:actionFunction name="redirect" action="{!Stats_In}"/>

<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, MSL2.Id)}" onclick="redirect(); return false"> TEST 
<apex:param assignTo="{!DL_Item}" value="{!MSL.berschrift__c}"/>                     
</apex:outputLink>
```

**CLASS:**

```
public PageReference Stats_In() {

Stats__c sta = new Stats__c(); 
sta.Item__c = DL_item;
INSERT sta;
RETURN NULL;
}
```

But If I click at the link the click information will be stored but the download doesn't start. The DL_Item name is not stored in the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

peXeq, You can go with below way.

**VFPage:**

```
<apex:page controller="DownloadFileController">  
     <apex:form>
           <apex:commandLink action="{!redirectToDownload}" value="Download" id="theButton"/>
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class DownloadFileController {


   public PageReference redirectToDownload() {
         // PUT you stats logic here 

         PageReference thePageReference =  new PageReference('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P2800000gYKZu');
         return thepageReference;
   }  

}
```

Output:
[image]
[image]

You can put your stats logic in controller method.